# specify a database name in databricks sql connection parameters

Tags: airflow, databricks, aws-databricks

I am using airflow 2.0.2 to connect with databricks using the airflow-databricks-operator. The SQL Operator doesn't let me specify the database where the query should be executed, so I have to prefix the `table_name` with `database_name`. I tried reading through the doc of databricks-sql-connector as well here -- https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html and still couldn't figure out if I could give the database name as a parameter in the connection string itself.

I tried setting `database/schema/namespace` in the `**kwargs`, but no luck. The query executor keeps saying that the table not found, because the query keeps getting executed in the default database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it's not supported - primarily reason is that if you have multiple statements then connector could reconnect between their execution, and result of `use` will be lost.  `databricks-sql-connector` also doesn't allow setting of the default database.

Right now you can workaround that by adding explicit `use <database>` statement into a list of SQLs to execute (the `sql` parameter could be a list of strings, not only string).

P.S. I'll look, maybe I'll add setting of the default catalog/database in the next versions

Comment: wow. thanks. it is insane to have the ability. i am looking to move from snowflake and doing a POC with databricks while keeping the system completely compatible with existing snowflake. this is the only hiccup.

Comment: One question - do you want to have these settings on the level of connection? Or in the operators? Can you drop me an email to alexott at gmail.com

Comment: PR is submitted: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22223